# Retrieve data from Ajax request and pass it to another api with php

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl, proxy

I am have set up a proxy that allows me to retrieve data user side from a api only accessible server side. I have several endpoints setup and they all work just fine, but now i'm at a point where I need to send data back to the api to make a reservation. I need to

1. retrieve data from ajax request in proxy
2. send data in proxy to api
3. return success/error message from api to ajax request

I not sure how to do this. Here is my ajax request:

```
var settings2 = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "http://url?method=hello&format=json&entity=" + id,
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": data,
            "method": "POST"
        };

        var a2 = $.ajax(settings2);

        $.when(a2).done(function(d2) {

            rp = d2;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(rp));

        });
```

and the php function and method I use for the other endpoints that only need to retrieve data from the api, it works for this:

```
function LocationReserve(data) {

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $url = 'api_url' . $_GET['entity'] ;
    $auth = 'Authorization: key';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            $auth
        ),
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

// Method A: Say Hello to the API
if( strcasecmp($_GET['method'],'hello') == 0){
    $response['code'] = 1;
    $response['status'] = $api_response_code[ $response['code'] ]['HTTP Response'];
    $response['data'] =  wssLocationReserve();
}

// --- Step 4: Deliver Response

// Return Response to browser
deliver_response($_GET['format'], $response);
```

with this as it is I get a response back

```
{"code":1,"status":200,"data":"{\"Message\":\"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.\"}"}
```

I added CURLOPT_POST => true to my options and now the response is

```
{"code":1,"status":200,"data":"<html><head><title>411 Invalid Request</title></head><body>Invalid Request: ??</body>\r\n"}
```

How can I modify this to accept the data from my ajax call, send it to the api_url, and send back the response?

**EDIT example expected data by api:

```
{
        "ReservationDay": "05/15/2015",
        "Units": [{
            "UnitID": 12345,
            "InsuranceID": 123 (or null)
         }],
        "PaymentInfo": {
            "FirstName": "User",
            "LastName": "Userson",
            "Address1": "2727 N Central Ave",
            "Address2": "",
            "City": "Phoenix",
            "State": "AZ",
            "Zip": "85022",
            "Phone": "602-2877878",
            "Email": "email@example.com",
            "CreditCard": "6011000000000000",
            "ExpirationMMYY": "1215",
            "CSC": "100"
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for **POST** rather than **GET**. With cURL, you need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`.

Comment: I added CURLOPT_POST => true to my options and now the response is {"code":1,"status":200,"data":"<html><head><title>411 Invalid Request</title></head><body>Invalid Request: ??</body>\r\n"}

Answer (score 0):

"*HTTP Status Code 411 (Length Required) is sent by the server as a response when it refuses to accept a message without a content-length header, for whatever reason.*"

1.- Test a request sending possible missing arguments.

2.- Have you the format in which the data must be send to the second endpoint?  Check the specifications of the expected data and fix your second request.

Comment: I have an example of how the data should look that comes from their docs, I'll place it in my question, but my data loops exactly the same including if the value is a string or an int, etc.